# Git commits linked to wrong user on Github, correct in git log output

Tags: git, github, debian, git-commit

I have been using git for some months now. I am working primarily on my own, working on a [repository](http://github.com/pocketapocketa/Radical_Transparency) primarily of .html and .txt files with a little (terrible) python. My coding skills are average at best, and I have been using linux & the unix command line for 2 years at a fairly basic level.

While I was visiting my parents in the UK, I installed git on their Mac Mini to continue working on my repository. I then set up a second repo for a different purpose and used git config in that repo to set up local values for user.email user.name etc. I set up a second github account using a different email address and pushed to it once.

Since then, every time I push from my 1st git repository on my own computer, the commits are listed as being by the second user set up on the mac, though I never pushed there from my own computers. The output of git log on my local repo has the author as what it ought to be "Author: pocketapocketa ", but github has it as "Christopher-Rozruch". (In fact, looking over the commit history, the "Christopher-Rozruch" commits pre-date my use of the Mac Mini and the setting up of the Christopher-Rozruch identity in any form by a week or so.)

I have searched for this problem but only found issues involving changed config files, multiple accounts on the same computer etc. [Github's own help on the topic](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/) discusses conflicts involving the same e-mail address associated with different accounts, which is not the case here.

I have found a script to retrospectively change the git history if I decide to do this (nobody else is working on the project), but I would like to understand why this has happened.

I have pushed to the primary repo in question from 2 computers in this time: one running on a MacBook, and one on Debian 8. The git version on Debian from which I have most recently pushed is 2.1.4. The others should be similar. The problem has been the same on each.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub associates commits to GitHub users by the email used in the commit, see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/).

Looking at your repository's history, we see that you have two different commit emails being used:

```
Author: pocketapocketa <pocketapocketa@yahoo.com>
```

This one seems to be associated with the [Christopher-Rozruch](https://github.com/Christopher-Rozruch) user.

```
Author: pocketapocketa <pocketapocketaqueep@yahoo.com>
```

This one seems to be associated with the [pocketapocketa](https://github.com/pocketapocketa) user.

Check your local settings, and be sure you have the appropriate email set. Additionally, if you own both of these accounts, you can unlink the email from one and assign it to the other if you want (this will clear up the GitHub history as well).

Comment: Thank you. I had glanced over the Christopher-Rozruch user and seen that I had indeed set the **primary** e-mail to a not-yet-used email address. I had thought I had avoided using the e-mail linked to my other account but I had used it as a backup until I was confident with the passphrase of the new e-mail etc. My bad. Changing the local e-mail changed the latest commit to the correct user. Deleting the common e-mail from the Christopher-Rozruch account retrospectively changed the commit history.